# lines() function is not connecting the actual points in the graph

Tags: r, graph, visualization

I have been practicing the graphs and how to plot in R with the following code

```
theta = 1:100
x = sin(theta)
y = cos(theta)
op = par(bg = 'white', mar = rep(1, 4))
plot.new()
plot(x,y)
plot.window(xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1))
lines(x, y, col = hsv(0.95, 1, 1))
```

to get the following output
[image]

Now I wanted to trace just how exactly the lines connect to form this pattern and so used the following code.

```
theta = 1:3
x = sin(theta)
y = cos(theta)
op = par(bg = 'white', mar = rep(1, 4))
plot(x,y, xlab = "Sin", ylab = "Cos", type = "p")
plot.window(xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1))
lines(x, y, col = hsv(0.95, 1, 1))
```

And I get the following output
[image]

Shouldn't the lines connect the dots? I get the output where the lines connect the dots using this code

```
theta = 1:3
x = sin(theta)
y = cos(theta)
op = par(bg = 'white', mar = rep(1, 4))
plot(x,y, xlab = "Sin", ylab = "Cos", type = "l")
```

[image]

And if I add the points later, they don't work as well.

```
theta = 1:3
x = sin(theta)
y = cos(theta)
op = par(bg = 'white', mar = rep(1, 4))
plot(x,y, xlab = "Sin", ylab = "Cos", type = "l")
plot.window(xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1))
points(x, y)
```

Here is the output. 
[image]

Why is there such difference in output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `plot.window` limits after you have plotted your points `plot(...)` and before plotting your lines `lines(...)` causing the mismatch. Try the following:

```
theta = 1:3
x = sin(theta)
y = cos(theta)
op = par(bg = 'white', mar = rep(1, 4))
plot.window(xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1))
plot(x,y, xlab = "Sin", ylab = "Cos", type = "p")
lines(x, y, col = hsv(0.95, 1, 1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right. Why does the plot.window() cause such a change?

Comment: You are changing the x and y limits of the plotting window after the first plot has already been generated.

Comment: So the plot.window() doesn't adjust the old graph to the new limits?

Comment: No it does not. Note changes affect the rest of the session after `plot.window` is called and all subsequent plots until the window is closed.  If you want to change just the limits of just the particular plot you can set limits in the plot call `plot(x,y, xlab = "Sin", ylab = "Cos", type = "p", xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1))` instead.